# How to create a collection of objects from a JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, class, object

I'm learning Swift and want to make an app that will show the GPS coordinates of buses on a map. The bus lat and lon come from a JSON (excerpt below):

```
    {
   "result":[
      {
         "Lat":52.276408,
         "Lon":21.167618,
         "Time":"2018-08-24 11:50:05",
         "Lines":"225",
         "Brigade":"4"
      },
      {
         "Lat":52.222656,
         "Lon":21.102633,
         "Time":"2018-08-24 11:51:03",
         "Lines":"225",
         "Brigade":"2"
      },
      {
         "Lat":52.2100185,
         "Lon":21.2054211,
         "Time":"2018-08-24 11:51:08",
         "Lines":"119",
         "Brigade":"2"
      },
      {
         "Lat":52.1676735,
         "Lon":21.2222606,
         "Time":"2018-08-24 11:51:07",
         "Lines":"213",
         "Brigade":"3"
      }
    ]
}
```

I was thinking of creating a Bus class

```
class Bus {

    var latitude : Double = 1.11
    var longitude : Double = 2.22
    var lines : Int = 0

    init (lat: Double, lon: Double, line: Int) {

        latitude = lat
        longitude = lon
        lines = line

    }   
}
```

But I'm trying to figure out how to create a collection of these bus objects from the JSON, which (in full) contains around 1000 objects (amount varies throughout the day).

Could someone point me in the right direction? I don't need the fully-coded solution, just some pointers on how should I approach this.

I will most likely be using the SwiftyJSON CocoaPod for JSON parsing, together with Alamofire for getting it.

Thank you!

Comment: `Codable`, that's a good key word to look for, in order to do what you want in Swift 4+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Below `Codable` class as **Larme** said in the comments.

```
import Foundation

class MyModelClass: Codable {
    let result: [Result]

    init(result: [Result]) {
        self.result = result
    }
}

class Result: Codable {
    let lat, lon: Double
    let time, lines, brigade: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case lat = "Lat"
        case lon = "Lon"
        case time = "Time"
        case lines = "Lines"
        case brigade = "Brigade"
    }

    init(lat: Double, lon: Double, time: String, lines: String, brigade: String) {
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon
        self.time = time
        self.lines = lines
        self.brigade = brigade
    }
}
```

If you wanted to use [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) then you can use below class

```
import Foundation 
import ObjectMapper 

class MyModelClass: Mappable { 

    var result: [Result]? 

    required init?(map: Map){ 
    } 

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        result <- map["result"] 
    }
} 

class Result: Mappable { 

    var lat: NSNumber? 
    var lon: NSNumber? 
    var time: String? 
    var lines: String? 
    var brigade: String? 

    required init?(map: Map){ 
    } 

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        lat <- map["Lat"] 
        lon <- map["Lon"] 
        time <- map["Time"] 
        lines <- map["Lines"] 
        brigade <- map["Brigade"] 
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: if a **class** adopts `Codable` the compiler won't complain about *missing initializers* so you can delete them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! And if I would go with the Codable class, how a for in loop would look like?

Comment: @MarcinGalus Why you need loop??

Comment: Oh yes, sorry - disregard that!

Answer (score 0):

write List model like this

```
class BusListModel {

var list = [Bus]()
var longitude : Double = 2.22
var lines : Int = 0

   init (With dict:[String:Any]) {
       if let result = dict["result"] as? [[String:Any]]{
           for busDetail in result{
            let model = Bus(lat: **valueHere**, lon: **valueHere**, line: **valueHere**)
             list.append(model)
            }

         }
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you all for the answers, especially @dahiya_boy**

I customised the code posted by @dahiya_boy and ended up with exactly what I need.

Below is the code. I created a `jsonString` for example purposes.

```
import Foundation

    class MyModelClass: Codable {
        let busArray: [Bus]

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case busArray = "result"
        }

        init(busArray: [Bus]) {
            self.busArray = busArray
        }
    }

    class Bus: Codable {
        let lat, lon: Double
        let time, lines, brigade: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case lat = "Lat"
            case lon = "Lon"
            case time = "Time"
            case lines = "Lines"
            case brigade = "Brigade"
        }

        init(lat: Double, lon: Double, time: String, lines: String, brigade: String) {
            self.lat = lat
            self.lon = lon
            self.time = time
            self.lines = lines
            self.brigade = brigade
        }
    }

    var jsonString = """

    {
    "result":[
    {
    "Lat":52.276408,
    "Lon":21.167618,
    "Time":"2018-08-24 11:50:05",
    "Lines":"225",
    "Brigade":"4"
    },
    {
    "Lat":52.222656,
    "Lon":21.102633,
    "Time":"2018-08-24 11:51:03",
    "Lines":"225",
    "Brigade":"2"
    },
    {
    "Lat":52.2100185,
    "Lon":21.2054211,
    "Time":"2018-08-24 11:51:08",
    "Lines":"119",
    "Brigade":"2"
    },
    {
    "Lat":52.1676735,
    "Lon":21.2222606,
    "Time":"2018-08-24 11:51:07",
    "Lines":"213",
    "Brigade":"3"
    }
    ]
    }

    """

    if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {

        let decodedJSON = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyModelClass.self, from: jsonData)

        print("Latitude: \(decodedJSON.busArray[0].lat), Longitude: \(decodedJSON.busArray[0].lon), Line: \(decodedJSON.busArray[0].lines)")

    }
```

This prints the following console output:

```
Latitude: 52.276408, Longitude: 21.167618, Line: 225
```